# Why doesn't my paintbox image appear when the form activates

Tags: delphi

I'm attempting to write an analog VU meter. I use a bitmap of a VU meter and draw the needle on to the bitmap. I am using a trackbar and it's onChange event to test the meter:

```
procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  angle : integer;
  x,y : integer;
  Peaked : boolean;
begin
   Angle := 120 - Round(sTrackBar1.Position / sTrackBar1.Max * 100 )+20;
   Peaked := Angle < PeakVol;
   if Peaked then
    Buffer.Picture := VUImagePeaked.Picture
   else
    buffer.picture := VUImage.Picture;
   buffer.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := clSilver;
   buffer.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Width:=2;
   buffer.Canvas.MoveTo(pivot.x,Pivot.y);
   x := 150 + Round(Cos(DegToRad(Angle)) * NeedleLen);
   y := PaintBox1.Height - Round(Sin(DegToRad(Angle)) *NeedleLen);
   buffer.Canvas.LineTo(x,y);
   PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,buffer.Picture.Bitmap)
end;
```

Seems to work but what I can't get is to display the bitmap of the meter when the program starts. I have even resorted to copying the above code to both the Form.Create and Form.Activate event handlers but no joy. I created a button and added the following code to trigger the onChange event handler for the trackbar. This works and displays the meter.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrackBar1.Position := 1;
end;
```

When I copied this to the Form.Activate handler it doesn't. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Delphi Berlin starter edition. Thanks

Comment: `PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,buffer.Picture.Bitmap)` - this needs to be moved to the `TPaintBox.OnPaint` event.

Answer (score 4):

A [`TPaintBox`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ExtCtrls_TPaintBox.html) must be painted using its `OnPaint` event. This event is triggered every time Windows needs you to redraw the control. You can't simply draw to the control's `Canvas` at any time, because it will just be drawn over the next time the control is repainted.

In your particular case, you don't need to move your entire block of code to the `OnPaint` event handler. Instead, all you need is:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,buffer.Picture.Bitmap)
end;
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for getting back to me so quickly. Using the onPaint event worked.